# Is $1=e^{i2n\pi}$ always true?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Suppose I have two Riemann sheets corresponding to the branches of $f(z)=z^{\frac{1}{2}}$, are the top and bottom sheets completely identical? i.e are $z_1$ and $z_2$ equal if $z_1$ and $z_2$ coincide as seen from the top of the Riemann surface? Or should we say that in the top sheet $z$ is of the form $re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and in the bottom sheet $\theta \in [2\pi,4\pi)$? Because if the latter is true, $e^{2\pi i}$ would map to $-1$ and $e^{4\pi i}$ would map to $+1$, which are different points. And so, the points need to be "different".

Comment: I'm not what you mean by "completely identical." The Riemann surface corresponding to $\sqrt{z}$ is cut out by the equation $z = w^2$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. This has the automorphism $(z,w) \mapsto (z, -w)$ which exchanges the two sheets. In that sense the sheets are identical.

Comment: My problem is due to the fact that "identical points" on different sheets map to different points on the complex plane. Is it due to the fact that the "argument"(not the argument function, but the argument of $z$ itself) of $z$ increases by $2\pi$ in the lower sheet?

Comment: I don't think the "identical points" map to different points in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $S$ be the surface $z = w^2$ I defined above. Then the map $S \to \mathbb{C}$ is simply $(z,w) \mapsto z$, so $(z,w)\mapsto z$ and $(z, -w) \mapsto z$, too. The idea is that $w$ is $\sqrt{z}$, and choosing the point $(z,w)$ or $(z,-w)$ on $S$ is the same as choosing a branch of $\sqrt{z}$.